# Can these selfreferential statements be rewritten as such?

Tags: logic, paradox, self-reference

1. This statement is a paradox = this statement is both true and false
2. this statement is a hypodox = this statement is either true or false
3. this statement is a contradiction/always false = this statement is false
4. this statement is a tautology/always true = this statement is true

Are these equalities true?

Comment: No. 4 is harmless: if the statement saying of itself that it is true is true, there is no contradiction. If it is false, then it is false, because it says of itself the false. But this does not mean that it is a tautology = always true. 3 is the well-known Liar paradox, defeating the assumption that every sentence has a definite truth value.

Comment: No none of the propositions you stated are equivalent.  That is you may not Express the same idea on the left side of the equal side to be the same idea expressed as the right hand side of the equal sign. A paradox is a more of a rhetorical device than deductive reasoning as it deliberately is vague in many respects to hinder the value of true or false. If a paradox was more specific it would be solved. 2 is a description that also applies to contingencies so it is not just hypodox it describes. 3 is about contradictory relationships. You need to distinguish Math definitions from deductive.

Comment: To continue on statement 3, A contradiction is a relationship not a definition. That is you need at least two or more claims to for a contradiction whether you see the two claims or not. All women are reptiles is a claim that is always false but is not a contradiction alone.  You would have to know by experience or have other information such as a definition to know some thing is wrong with the claim. There are claims that are always false but are not contradictions. So claim 3 is not equivalent as you are comparing a math definition to an actual relationship of propositions.

Comment: Claim 4 is also based on a definition in math so it has problems with reality.  Can you find claims that are always true but not tautological? YES, you can such as all human beings have human DNA. You can't define a human being by DNA alone as there are other factors to makes a human being what they're are. Them having human DNA is only one factor of many factors for the definition of what makes a life a human being. Abortion would not be debated if there were clear evidence of what a human being was for instance. In this way can you have claims always true without tautology? In reality YES.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA To be fair, in light of [Lob's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem) the assertion that "This statement is true" can consistently be false is not one I'm entirely comfortable making without argument.